# How do I put multiple lines within a (single) pair of curly brackets?

Tags: align

I am trying to define a set by putting description of it in a pair of curly brackets like "{ }". The problem is the definition is sort of long and it looks messy with everything in a single line.

Instead, I tried to use "align" environment. It came out with two lines, however, it could only show the left bracket on the first line but not the right one on the second. I guess it was because the "\" kind of broke the coherence.

So is there any way I can put multiple lines (at least two lines) in a pair of curly brackets as a set? Thank you.

Below are what I have tried as mentioned above.

```
\begin{equation}
\Theta_{I}\equiv  \left\{ \theta: [b_{n^{\prime }}(\alpha )-b_{n}(\alpha )]+\theta [R_{n^{\prime}}(\alpha )-R_{n}(\alpha )]\geq 0, \; \forall \alpha \in [0,1], 
  \forall n^{\prime},n \in \mathcal{N}, \quad n^{\prime}>n, \quad G_{n},G_{n^{\prime}}\in \mathcal{G}_{R}, \quad \theta \in \Theta \right\}    % how to add {} in an equation mode
\end{equation}



\begin{align}
\Theta_{I}\equiv & \left\{ \theta: [b_{n^{\prime }}(\alpha )-b_{n}(\alpha )]+\theta [R_{n^{\prime}}(\alpha )-R_{n}(\alpha )]\geq 0, \; \forall \alpha \in [0,1], \\
  &\forall n^{\prime},n \in \mathcal{N}, \quad n^{\prime}>n, \quad G_{n},G_{n^{\prime}}\in \mathcal{G}_{R}, \quad \theta \in \Theta \right\} \notag   % how to add {} in an equation mode
  \label{eq7}
\end{align}
```

Comment: although I think you should use `split` or `multline` instead of `align` and `\left` and `\right` are not needed, you have to put `\right.` in your first line and `\left.` in the second one, respectively to close and open the curly brackets. This http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23576/27635 might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My proposal is to use `multline`, avoiding big braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\Theta_{I}\equiv
  \{\theta:
  [b_{n'}(\alpha )-b_{n}(\alpha)] + \theta[R_{n'}(\alpha)-R_{n}(\alpha)]\geq 0,\\
  \forall \alpha \in [0,1], \quad
  \forall n',n \in \mathcal{N}, \quad
  n'>n, \quad
  G_{n},G_{n'}\in\mathcal{G}_{R}, \quad
  \theta\in\Theta\}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good. But how to control the amount of indent for the second line?

Comment: @JieWei You can try with `split`, but it's customary, for a single equation broken across lines, just to left align the starting piece and right align the end (with some clearance in both places).